# How would I iterate through a collection's child and group them by category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of a users workouts. A workout contains a collection of exercises. Each exercise has a category.

I'd like to iterate over the collection of workouts and group them by the exercise category.

The thing that is throwing me off is that the `exercise_workouts` is a join model. For example:

`#<ExerciseWorkout id: 50, exercise_id: 14, workout_id: 42, description: nil, created_at: "2013-03-12 08:15:17", updated_at: "2013-03-12 08:15:17", user_id: nil>`

```
.exercises
  %h1.exercise-type-title Lifting Exercises
  = render @workout.exercise_workouts
```

I'd like to render the `@workout.exercise_workouts` part group'd by the available categories through the exercises. So I would see something like

```
.exercises
  %h1.exercise-type-title Lifting Exercises
  = render @workout.exercise_workouts (lifting)
  %h1.exercise-type-title Running Exercises
  = render @workout.exercise_workouts (running)
```

Not sure how to go about this? And also would prefer not to hardcode each category and just list what's available through an intelligent iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following (i'm not sure if i've got the name of the partial correct which is based on the class of `exercise_workouts`)

```
@workout.exercise_workouts.group_by(&:category).each do |category, exercises|
  = render partial: '/exercise_workouts/exercise_workout', collection: exercises, locals: { category: category }
```

UPDATE: accessing category on `exercise`

You can change the loop to look like

```
@workout.exercise_workouts.group_by { |ew| ew.exercise.category }.each do |category, exercises|
  = render partial: '/exercise_workouts/exercise_workout', collection: exercises, locals: { category: category }
```

or you can delegate the category attribute to exercise on the exercise_workout model

```
#exercise_workout.rb
delegate :category, to: :exercise
```

and still use the first version. Personally, I prefer the second solution.

Comment: undefined method `category' for #<ExerciseWorkout:0x007fc06d5ee180>. #category is available off of exercise. Hmmm...

Comment: ExerciseWorkout looks like this: #<ExerciseWorkout id: 50, exercise_id: 14, workout_id: 42, description: nil, created_at: "2013-03-12 08:15:17", updated_at: "2013-03-12 08:15:17", user_id: nil>

Comment: I agree. Using delegate is very nice in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: I get undefined local variable or method `category' for #<#<Class:0x007fc072146740>:0x007fc072b26ad0>
using second method.

Comment: hmm. not really sure where that error comes from. can you check your list of exercise workouts and make sure that all of them have an exercise association? `delegate` will raise an exception on nil association unless you pass `allow_nil`

Comment: Ah I see. So the partial is expecting the object to be exercise_workout, what we're passing in is a collection of exercises instead so there's nils. Actually wait no that's wrong, it should be exercise_workouts.. hmmm

Comment: Really weird... somehow it just magically worked. That was odd.

Comment: yep. i used a wrong variable name. exercises in the answer should be an array of exercise_workout objects.